# How to assign a pointer to a Go map

Tags: pointers, dictionary, go

I am having problems assigning a pointer to a map.  Maybe this is a bug in Go? Or maybe I am just doing something wrong. The code is here on the playground as well, https://play.golang.org/p/p0NosPtkptz

Here is some super simplified code that illustrates the problem.  I am creating an object called collections that has two collection objects in it. I am then looping through those collections and assigning them to a map where the key in the map is the collection ID.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type collection struct {
    ID string
    Name string
}

type collections struct {
    Collections []collection
}

type cache struct {
    Index int
    Collections map[string]*collection
}

func main() {
    var c cache
    c.Collections = make(map[string]*collection)

    // Create 2 Collections
    var col1, col2 collection
    col1.ID = "aa"
    col1.Name = "Text A"
    col2.ID = "bb"
    col2.Name = "Test B"

    // Add to Collections
    var cols collections
    cols.Collections = append(cols.Collections, col1)
    cols.Collections = append(cols.Collections, col2)
    fmt.Println("DEBUG Collections Type", cols)

    i := 0
    for k, v := range cols.Collections {
        c.Index = i
        c.Collections[v.ID] = &v
        fmt.Println("DEBUG k", k)
        fmt.Println("DEBUG v", v)
        i++
    }
    fmt.Println("Collection 1", c.Collections["aa"].ID)
    fmt.Println("Collection 2", c.Collections["bb"].ID)
    fmt.Println(c)
}
```

The output from this playground code looks like:

```
DEBUG Collections Type {[{aa Text A} {bb Test B}]}
DEBUG k 0
DEBUG v {aa Text A}
DEBUG k 1
DEBUG v {bb Test B}
Collection 1 bb
Collection 2 bb
{1 map[aa:0x1040a0f0 bb:0x1040a0f0]}
```

So it seems like the map is for some reason getting the same pointer for each entry. All of the "DEBUG" lines print out what I would expect. However, the three print lines at the very end, do not.  Collection 1 should be "aa" not "bb".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the code in the first answer has an error - a pointer to a local variable coll:

```
for k, v := range cols.Collections {
    coll := v
    c.Collections[v.ID] = &coll
```

Just try to change a property value of a collection:

```
cols.Collections[0].Name = "Text C"
fmt.Println("Collection 1", cols.Collections[0].Name)
fmt.Println("Collection 1", c.Collections["aa"].Name)
//  Collection 1 Text C
//  Collection 1 Text A
```

But the another code will print an expected result:

```
for k, v := range cols.Collections {
    c.Index = i
    p := &cols.Collections[k]
    c.Collections[v.ID] = p

....
cols.Collections[0].Name = "Text C"
fmt.Println("Collection 1", cols.Collections[0].Name)
fmt.Println("Collection 1", c.Collections["aa"].Name)
// Collection 1 Text C
// Collection 1 Text C
```

Comment: In Go, taking address to a local variable is perfectly fine. Go compiler deals with that by let the variable "escape" to the heap.

Comment: Getting the address of a local variable is normal.

But very often this is the cause of the error (closures, several collection, etc.), especcially unexpected suprice with bytes slices as a properties.

Second, using two or more copy of objects is a case of heavy usage memory and performance.

For this example, IMHO, there is an error for the case of two or more collections as indexes.

Comment: Your solution is another use case scenario.  What if OP wants to separate `slice` and `map`. You can explain pros and cons. But its not wise to say that my solution has an error.

Answer (score 6):

When you are putting `&v` into `c.Collections[v.ID]`, you are actually assigning same address of loop variable `v`.

This address finally holds the last value of your list. That's why you are getting `bb Test B` for all key.

Print these value and you will see same address.

```
fmt.Printf("%p\n", c.Collections["aa"])
fmt.Printf("%p\n", c.Collections["bb"])
```

And by copying it to a new variable in the loop scope, the issue is solved. Each step in the loop you will put a new and unique address into the cache.

```
for k, v := range cols.Collections {
    coll := v
    c.Collections[v.ID] = &coll
    fmt.Println("DEBUG k", k)
    fmt.Println("DEBUG v", v)
    i++
}
```

Comment: Copying the id is not needed and use a underscore in variable is adviced against in Go. And I think you should mention why one should do this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer about same pointer is a map contains the address of a variable v, but not array items.

```
for k, v := range cols.Collections {
   ......
   c.Collections[v.ID] = &v
```

A right solution is storing a pointer to array, but not a value.

```
type collections struct {
     Collections []*collection
}

cols.Collections = append(cols.Collections, &col1)
cols.Collections = append(cols.Collections, &col2)
```

Or get address of map item (as the answer higher)

```
for k, v := range cols.Collections {
    c.Index = i
    p := &cols.Collections[k]
    c.Collections[v.ID] = p
```

Comment: There is a difference between taking address of a copied value and of the one stored in the slice: will the map's value change if the slice value change? Though it is not specified by OP, I think it makes better sense to make two independent of each other.

Comment: The matter os usage. Storing addresses of the same objects is important for the two collections as indexes to access one.